# JS file not present in build.js, but creates the other JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-dom

I am trying to create a project with React and Webpack. I am new in using these, but none of the solutions found related to the error that I have did work.

I have my StartPage.html, using StartPage.js which builds, is present in bundle.js and runs perfectly.

StartPage.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Copyright application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="ImageUploader.html">Image Upload</a>
    <div id="root2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

StartPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
class StartPage extends Component {

 render() {
      return (
        <div> StartPage </div>
 );
 }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StartPage />,
  document.getElementById('root2')
);


export default StartPage
```

But now I have ImageUploader.html which is build in the same style, but with a more complex side on ImageUploader.js

ImageUploader.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Upload Image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

ImageUploader.js - just the render and the DOM

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ImageUploader">
        <nav className="navbar pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
          <a href="#" className="pure-menu-heading pure-menu-link">IPFS File Upload DApp</a>
        </nav>

        <main className="container">
          <div className="pure-g">
            <div className="pure-u-1-1">
              <h1>Your Image</h1>
              <p>This image is stored on IPFS & The Ethereum Blockchain!</p>
              <h2>Upload Image</h2>
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
                <input type='file' onChange={this.captureFile} />
                <input type='submit' />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ImageUploader />,
  document.getElementById('image')
);

export default ImageUploader
```

This one is not created in bundle.js, although the webpack creates it.
[Webpack folder after npm run build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8sWv.png)

But I have this error in the console:  _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element .. which I have exhaustively researched and none of the found solutions worked for me: like changing the order of the div id="" with the bundle.js script
[like this one, where the script is created automatically by webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnA59.png)

I have spent quite a lot of time on this error or trying to find another solution to create the multiple pages with Webpack.

This is webpack.config.prod.js and dev is defined in the same way regarding the pages:

webpack.config.prod.js

```
  plugins: [

    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
      PUBLIC_URL: publicUrl
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/public/StartPage.html',
           inject: true,
           chunks: ['start'],
           filename: 'StartPage.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: './src/public/ImageUploader.html',
          inject: true,
          chunks: ['image'],
          filename: 'ImageUploader.html'
        }),
```

And I have specified the .js file in the entry of module.exports:

```
  entry: {
    image: './src/ImageUploader/ImageUploader.js',
    start: './src/StartPage/StartPage.js'
```

If someone has an idea about what could be wrong with this..

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to use a Component named ImageUpLoader that isn't defined anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: @RandyCasburn What do you mean by not defined anywhere? I am not really sure where should the ImageUploader be defined in another place.

Comment: From ImageUploader.js, I included only the render function and the DOM. This is the header:
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import SimpleStorageContract from '../../build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json'
    import getWeb3 from './../utils/getWeb3'
    import ipfs from './../ipfs'
    
    import '../css/oswald.css'
    import '../css/open-sans.css'
    import '../css/pure-min.css'
    import './ImageUploader.css'
    
    class ImageUploader extends Component {.....

Comment: let me ask a different way: The `render()` function that you've defined...how do you suppose that is being used?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I thought it's called by the ReactDOM.render() which is below the render, as it works for the StartPage?

Comment: Well there you go, what is the difference between the render() method used on the start page and the one on the `ImageUploader.js `? The first page creates and exports a Class named `StartPage` that **extends Component** from React. Then, the render method is inside that class. When the component is used inside the JSX, React is able to find it, instantiate the class, and call **the components** render method.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I see what you mean now. This was created because of this line from ImageUploader.js: <img src={`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${this.state.ipfsHash}`} alt=""/> where the jsx wasn't taking the last '}' because of the quotes and it created a confusion ... but with this removed, I am still in the same state with the same error and the render is now included in the class.. thank you very much for seeing this though

Comment: @RandyCasburn is that what you referred to? because of that line it did not include the render in the class? It is still in the same error state after clarifying those parenthesis..

Comment: No...you need to go read about React Components, the render method of a component and how they work: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @RandyCasburn I had a look over how it works before. I don't believe it is related to it, but to how I have defined it in webpack, as this JS worked perfectly before trying to create the StartPage